# DropzoneJs files save order to database

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

I am working on a project which involves file uploading. I am using DropzoneJS and Laravel for this project. Everything seems to work fine.

I want to save files with order. I want to pass the image order and save image file in that order.

My code:

```
var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
var token = "{{ Session::getToken() }}";

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
    url: baseUrl + "/upload",
    params: {
        _token: token

    }
});
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName: "flyers",
    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
    enqueueForUpload: true,
    forceFallback: false,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drop files here to upload",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: false,
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    accept: function(file, done) {

    },
};
```

my controller

```
    public function album()
   {
$file = Input::file('file');

$destinationPath = 'uploads';
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

$uploadSuccsess = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
   if( $uploadSuccsess ) {
     return Response::json('success', 200);
   } else {
     return Response::json('error', 400);
   }

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question you'd like to ask?

Comment: how i can save the filename as order to database?